# iterating through dictionary using nested foreach

Tags: c#

This is a nested dictionary pair with the below sample data.

```
{"A-BC-1111/AB.CD":{"P1":"F","P2":"0.0"}
```

I am trying to iterate through it and create a collection class like this:

```
public class FromDic
{
    string Name = "A-BC-1111/AB.CD";
    Attr1 = "F";
    Attr2 = "0.0";
}
```

I am trying to do nested foreach like this:

```
FromDic collectiondic=new FromDic();

foreach(var Key in MyDic)
{
    collectionDic.Name=Key;

    // key on the inner loop is for “Type” and “Val”
    foreach (var key in obj.Keys)
    {
        IJsonValue val;

        if (!obj.TryGetValue(key, out val))
            continue;

        switch (key)
        {
            case "P1":
                collectionDic.Attr1 = val.GetString();
                break;
            case "P2":
                collectionDic.Attr2 = val.GetNumber().ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

But my code doesn't compile. Anything I can do to make this nested `foreach` work ?

Comment: "Doesn't compile" is vague. I'm guessing that the error is on the `TryGetValue` line, since it expects an `out string`, but you try to `out` it into an `IJsonValue`. Try to `out` it into a `string` and parse to `IJsonValue` afterwards in some manner.

Comment: Also, when reformatting your code I noticed that you were missing a closing '}' at the end. Make sure that the problem isn't it.

Comment: if `obj` is a Dictionary, don't bother iterating on its keys then doing a second lookup to get its value. Instead just iterate on its keyvalue pairs (`foreach(var entry in obj)`).

Comment: what is the type for `MyDic` and the type for `obj`?

Comment: @Tejas If only it somehow inherited from `long`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am referring to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397290/implementing-iobservable-on-dictionary-object-and-assigning-key-values-to-xaml-e) and assuming you are using Json.net

```
var list = jObj.Children()
            .Cast<JProperty>()
            .Select(p => new FromDic()
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                Attr1 = (string)p.Value["P1"],
                Attr2 = (string)p.Value["P2"]
            })
            .ToList();
```

---

```
public class FromDic
{
    public string Name;
    public string Attr1;
    public string Attr2;
}
```

Comment: Never thought of the horizontal separator as a code paragraph breaker. Cool :P